# Tracing unmanaged DirectX objects allocated through Managed DirectX

Tags: directx, managed-directx

I have a problem where Device.Dispose() is taking a long time to execute when the application is closed. I am investigating whether this is due to unmanaged objects not being freed properly thus resulting in a long cleanup time.

Is there an easy way of tracing or viewing the unmanaged DirectX objects that have been allocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out a way to trace all the calls made to DirectX.

Download and install the DirectX SDK (I installed the August 2009).

Run an application called **PIX for Windows** in the DirectX SDK -> DirectX Utilities

Create a new experiment from the File menu. Select "a replayable Direct3D call stream, saved to file:", enter a filename and select your application.

When you exit your application a complete trace of all DirectX calls will be shown complete with a timeline.